# Edittext.getText().toString(); is not working android

Tags: android, android-edittext, tostring

I'm new to android developing. I started to make a login screen first but getting entered text is not working. I do not know why. I have been using log and toast but its getting here is code of mine. Toast shows empty and tag wont even appear on debug window and yes I have those fields in layout file.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TAG = "LoginInfo";
EditText txtusername, txtpassword;
Button button;
String username, password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    username = txtusername.getText().toString();
    password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, username + password);
            if ((!username.isEmpty()) & (!password.isEmpty())) {
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("USERNAME", username);
                editor.putString("PASSWORD", password);
                editor.commit();
                Log.d(TAG, username + password);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered Login Info is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move

```
 username = txtusername.getText().toString();
 password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
```

inside `onClick()` because it's value is empty. when the view is created.

Comment: that means, to get the text from text field do i have to put inside of the action(button) always?

Comment: @Parshwa.introvert Yup. and/or another way is to set `text` as value after view created.like `txtusername.setText("Value");`

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below, you getText on onCreate that return blank because of no text in this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        username = txtusername.getText().toString();
        password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, username + password);
        if ((!username.isEmpty()) & (!password.isEmpty())) {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("USERNAME", username);
            editor.putString("PASSWORD", password);
            editor.commit();
            Log.d(TAG, username + password);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered Login Info is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TAG = "LoginInfo";
EditText txtusername, txtpassword;
Button button;
String username, password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        username = txtusername.getText().toString();
        password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, username + password);
        if ((!username.isEmpty()) & (!password.isEmpty())) {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Login_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("USERNAME", username);
            editor.putString("PASSWORD", password);
            editor.commit();
            Log.d(TAG, username + password);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entered Login Info is Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in `onCreate()` as you call `EditText.getText().toString();` when the view is created, so the user still has not entered any data. You should move them to the `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 0):

put these lines inside `onClick()`

```
username = txtusername.getText().toString();
password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
```

Each time you enter text into edittext you can get values `onClick()`.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
username = txtusername.getText().toString();
password = txtpassword.getText().toString();
```

These lines should not be there in onCreate(). Because initially , the EditTexts are empty.
As user gives the input, then only user would press Login Button.

So put the above mentioned lines within onClick() event of the button.

If the editTexts are found empty in onClick() event of the button , you should show the Toast message like :

> "Please provide the credentials to Login!"